# Access denied error while accessing com object from WCF service

Tags: wcf, com

I have a WCF service setup in a Windows server 2008 machine, I am accessing the service from a .net framework 2.0 windows application running in a windows 2000 machine. I was able to connect to the WCF service and execute a simple method. In my WCF service I have a reference to a COM dll, but when I try to call a method accessing this client COM object I get an error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {xxxxxxxxxxxxxx} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is
>   denied.

The `CLSID` is for com + application which is registered for the COM dll. I have added access to Network service, logged in user of the Windows 2000 system for the COM dll, the folder containing the COM dll also the folder having the WCF service but I still get the error.

Any tip on this would be very helpful

**Edit:**
I reregistered my com dll and the above error was gone, but i am getting a new error now

**Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {6F0FFDCA-CC2F-4008-ABE1-2E5F9F54A2A5} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8004e024.**

Comment: how are you hosting WCF service?

Comment: I am hosing the service on IIS

Answer (score 1):

You must give launch and access permission for application pool user(in this case network service i guess) in component service under administrative tools.